# Add custom field on signin form

Tags: meteor, meteor-useraccounts

Using meteor useraccounts package, I would like to add a custom field in `signIn` form (named `token`) to enable 2fa authentication.

Unfortunatly on `AccountTemplates.addField` only work with `signUp` form, as far as I have worked on it.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer i managed to implement was to change the pattern with a different approach, using directly Meteor API:

1. Set a special field on user collection: `tokenverified: false`
2. Add `Meteor.onLogin` (called each time you login or refresh manually the page) and `Meteor.onLogout` callback to set this field to false
3. Create a template `verify2FA` to deal with token and set `tokenverified: true`
4. Create an iron-router plugin `ensure2FA` that will check this token and redirect to the `verify2FA` template.

Answer (score 2):

The accounts package has an `Accounts.onLogin` function that you can use to call a method and update the user account.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user) {
  Meteor.call('setToken', user)
})
```

and then

```
Meteor.methods({
  setToken: function(user) {
    // Do some clever check
    Meteor.users.update(/* Set your token */);
  },
});
```

The advantage of using a method is that you can do some server-side check to ensure your token has not been hacked.

Comment: Yes managed to use this alternative. Needs also:
- some custom route to enforce 2FA on some pages
- detect if another client is logging in, otherwise you may login and set token and let other to login as well with only the password.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm missing something. What is the issue with your routing and multiple logging? Are you talking about two different clients trying to log in or the same one from two different pages?

Comment: I managed to make the whole thing working. Will make an answer with details